# Is it possible to expand a Hyper-V drive if there are checkpoints?

Tags: hyper-v

I have a Hyper-V VM with 3 checkpoints. Now I want to extend the virtual hard drive, but I cannot because there are checkpoints.

Is there a tool that would allow me to do it anyway? I would like to preserve the checkpoints, of course.

- Both the host and the guest machines are Windows 10.
- The drive is VHDX.
- The VM is Gen2.

Comment: VHD or VHDX?  Gen1 or Gen2?

Comment: Added the info.